# What's the different between inserted and bind in vue's directive

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I never use inserted in directive, but I saw it in the some other directive.

In vue's offical doc ,it says:

> bind: called only once, when the directive is first bound to the
>   element. This is where you can do one-time setup work.
>
> inserted: called when the bound element has been inserted into its
>   parent node (this only guarantees parent node presence, not
>   necessarily in-document).

I couldn't tell the difference. Is there any use case for that ?

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I get it. What the doc says is totally true.

```
bind: function (el) {
    console.log(el.parentNode)  // null
    console.log('bind')
},

inserted: function (el) {
    console.log(el.parentNode)  // <div id="app">...</div>
    console.log('inserted')
}
```

And the difference between update and componentUpdated

```
update: function (el) {
    console.log(el.innerHTML)   // Hello, before updated
    console.log('update')
},
componentUpdated: function (el) {
    console.log(el.innerHTML)   // Hi, after updated
    console.log('componentUpdated')
}
```

The answer comes from

> https://imys.net/20161216/vue-custom-directive-hook.html